# Google calendar notifications broken

Tags: iphone, google-calendar

On my iPhone 4, the Google calendar notifications have randomly stopped working. The notifications still pop up at the appropriate time, but the title of the event is hidden, so I have no idea what I'm actually being notified about. This has been happening for about a month.

Is the problem with the iPhone or with Google Calendar? Plzfix

[image]

See picture. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Could be the app. You can test it. Try to make a notification with the ios calendar app and see what that does. You may also want to look around if anyone else is reporting this behavior for the same app or in general.